# Proving that $L \le M$ as limits of $f$ and $g$ when $f(x) \le g(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, inequality

While doing some tasks for my next calculus course, I ran across this task:

"Let $a < b <c$, and assume that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x \in [a, c]$. If $\lim_{x \to b}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x \to b}g(x) = M$, prove that $L \le M$."

I have done some thinking about this, but I have to admit that I'm hopelessly stuck. A proof by contradiction seems natural here, so I'm assuming, for the sake of contradiciton, that $L > M$. From the limits we know, from the definition, that $|x - b| < \delta(\epsilon)$ and that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ and $|g(x) - M| < \epsilon$. Unconventionally, I tried setting $\epsilon < 1$ (yes, $\epsilon$, not $\delta$), getting $|f(x) - L| < 1$ and $|g(x) - M| < 1$. I'm having a hard time forcing a contradiction from this. We are left with the facts that $f(x) < 1 + L$ and $g(x) < 1 + M$.

While writing this, I thought that if I changed $\epsilon < 1$ to "very small $\epsilon$", we could force a contradiction from $f(x) < \epsilon + L$ and $g(x) < \epsilon + M$. For sufficiently small $\epsilon$ and $\delta(\epsilon)$, this would imply (I do not have **any** confidence in this statement whatsoever) $f(x) > g(x)$ for $L > M$, which is the desired contradiction, and we are done.

I'm new to these kind of proofs, and I'd highly appreciate to be spoonfed about my mistakes here.

Comment: The two functions are a red herring: you have only one, precisely $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$; you know that $h(x)\ge 0$ for $x\in[a,c]$ and that $\lim_{x\to b}h(x)$ exists. See Sami's answer, now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started very well.

To finish the proof, instead of setting $\epsilon=1$, try

$$\epsilon=\frac{L-M}{3}$$

Also, note that

$$|f(x) - L| < \frac{L-M}{3} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{L-M}{3} < f(x) - L < \frac{L-M}{3}$$
$$|g(x) - M| < \frac{L-M}{3} \Leftrightarrow -\frac{L-M}{3} < g(x) - M < \frac{L-M}{3}$$

Now combine these two inequalities with

$$g(x) -f(x) \geq 0$$

**Note** Intuitively, the proof reduces to the following: If $L>M$, as $f$ gets very close to $L$ and $g$ gets very close to $M$, we cannot have $g \geq f$. What we did, we split the interval $[M,L]$ in three thirds, and made sure that $f$ is in the top third, while $g$ is in the bottom third.

Comment: Yes, binding the $\epsilon$-value tends to confuse me, so I highly appreciate your edit where you elaborated. If I understand this right, from a less rigorous standpoint, "sufficiently small $\epsilon$" is also (intuitively) correct, but is not accurate enough?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Intuitively small enough is the right way of doing things, but formally you have to decide how small you need it. Also, note that the contradiction comes from $f(x)> L-\epsilon$ and $g(x)< M+\epsilon$. This should be clear as you want to prove that $f(x) > g(x)$, thus you make $f(x) >$ quantity 1 and quantity 2 $>g(x)$. Then as long as you can make $quantity 1 >quantity 2, you get the contradiction, and this tells you exactly how small, small enough is.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to prove that $\lim_{x\to b}f(x)=\ell\ge0$ if $f(x)\ge 0$.

**Hint** By definition we have
$$\ell-\epsilon<f(x)<\ell+\epsilon\quad \text{if}\; |x-b|<\delta$$
so by contradiction take $\epsilon=-\frac\ell 2$.

Comment: @JasperLoy: if $f(b)=\ell$, there would be no difference, but it is true that the limit can exist even if $f$ is not continuous at $b$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go "arbitrary small", otherwise you won't get the statement.

Suppose $L > M$, and call $\varepsilon = L-M > 0$. Then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x - b| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < L-M$. This means in particular that $L - f(x) < L - M$, i.e. $f(x) > M$. Also, there exists $\delta' > 0$ such that $0 < |x-b| < \delta'$ implies $|g(x) - M| < L-M$, which implies $g(x) < L$. Combining this together gives
$$
M < f(x) \le g(x) < L < M
$$
for $|x - b| < \min \{ \delta, \delta' \}$, a contradiction.

Hope that helps,

Comment: @JasperLoy : True, I just wasn't thorough.