# Proof verification: $f(x) \le g(x) \implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$

Tags: limits, inequality, proof-verification, self-learning, alternative-proof

I am self-teaching calculus using Spivak's book, and it's hard for me to know whether my proofs are correct, if they are different from the proofs that Spivak gives. Could you help me to check whether the following proof is correct?

([This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787242/fx-le-gx-implies-lim-x-to-afx-le-lim-x-to-agx) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478556/if-fx-le-gx-for-all-x-prove-that-lim-x-to-afx-le-lim-x-to-agx) questions show proofs to the same problem, but the logic of the proofs is different. The proofs in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619752/proving-that-l-le-m-as-limits-of-f-and-g-when-fx-le-gx) question seem to be the most similar to mine, but still I don't see clearly whether the logic there is the same one I am using or not.)

The problem is:

> Suppose that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all x. Prove that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) \le \lim_{x\to a}g(x)$, provided that these limits exist.

I use the proof by contradiction.

Suppose the limits exist and let

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = M$.

This means that that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that

If $ 0 < |x-a| < \delta_1$ then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$

and $\delta_2$ such that

if $0 <|x-a| < \delta_2$ then $|g(x) - M| < \epsilon$

We can rewrite the inequalities without the absolute values:

$L - \epsilon < f(x) < L + \epsilon$

$M - \epsilon < g(x) < M + \epsilon$

Now suppose that contrary to what we are trying to prove $L > M$. Then the two inequalities can be collapsed into one:

$M - \epsilon < L - \epsilon < f(x) \le g(x) < M + \epsilon < L + \epsilon$

From this inequality it follows that

$M - \epsilon < f(x) < M + \epsilon$

$L - \epsilon < g(x) < L + \epsilon$

that is

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = M$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = L$. Since in the beginning of the proof we let $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = M$, it follows that $L = M$. This contradicts our assumption that $L > M$, so it must be false.

Comment: This looks fine, provided you have already shown that the limit of a function is unique if it exists.

Comment: I am not sure what it means for a limit $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$ to not be unique if it exists.  If it exists, it's unique, no?

Comment: Your wording is not quite correct. You want to show that $L \le M$, so you suppose for the sake of contradiction that $L >M$. You are not trying to prove that $L>M$.

Comment: @avs Yes, but it's not immediate from the definition of limit; recall that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ means that some condition holds, so a priori there could be distinct values $L_1,L_2$ both satisfying the condition. The reason this can't happen is we could choose $\epsilon>0$ such that $2\epsilon<|L_1-L_2|$. This fact is being used in the OP's proof to show that if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)=M$ then $L=M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to start with a special case first. Suppose $\phi(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$, and $\lim_{x \to a} \phi(x)$ exists. Then we must have 
 $\lim_{x \to a} \phi(x) \ge 0$.

The proof by contradiction is straightforward, if $L=\lim_{x \to a} \phi(x) < 0$,
then there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $\|x-a\| < \delta$, then
$\phi(x) < {1 \over 2} L <0$ (remember $L<0$), which is a contradiction. Hence
$L \ge 0$.

Now use the fact that subtraction is continuous to deal with the general case by taking $\phi(x) = g(x)-f(x)$. Since $\phi(x) \ge 0$ w\everywhere, we see
that $\lim_{x \to a} (g(x)-f(x)) = \lim_{x \to a} g(x) - \lim_{x \to a} f
(x) \ge 0$ which is the desired result.

Comment: That's an interesting way to prove it; I have a small further question about L/2 in the special case("if $|x-a| < \delta$ then $\phi(x) < \frac{1}{2}L < 0$"). Am I correct to think that it comes from just choosing an arbitrary $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}L$?

Comment: Well, it comes from choosing $\epsilon = {1 \over 2} |L|$, remember that $L<0$. It is not entirely arbitrary, $\epsilon$ needs to be small enough to ensure that $\phi(x) < 0$ in some neighbourhood of $a$.